# Markov chains in Python - filling the transition matrix from another array and hitting probabilities

Tags: python, r, linear-algebra, markov-chains

Python or R (preferably Python, since I am better with arrays and loops there)

Suppose we have a two dimensional array A (of n^2 rows and n^2 columns) whose entries we have already filled in with for loops, using some complicated rules.

Now I want to create a Markov chain on n^2 states with transition matrix A and then compute the following hitting probability: the probability that, starting from (2,3), say, I ever reach a state corresponding to an integer which is a multiple of n.

How is this possible? Are there some nice library/package functions for this?

Update: I am also fine with not formally creating a chain but just a complicated system of equations which finds the hitting probability I am chasing.